# Add / Remove columns on regular basis required in c# using Sql server, what should be the best approach?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-attribute-value, nreco

In my application I'm allowing user to add/delete new fields to data base, so I  need to find a best solution of my regular column add/update/delete problem in sql server database, I'm c#.net developer,  and I usually work using Entity Framework. I have been googling this and came across EAV (Entity Attribute value) and then I found [EAV Model Db Storage for .Net](https://www.nrecosite.com/semantic_storage_net.aspx#) for c#.net. 
Source code is provided and I went through it its good thing. but do we have a better solution of my problem, as I could not find any documentation on how to use it in any application(asp.net mvc, wpf, winforms, console app)

What if **I do not want to combine traditional relational tables and entity-attribute-value(triplets)** in same database?

I am new to EAV and not sure how should I handle this case.I will highly appreciate any response on it.

EDIT: I have found this: https://www.nrecosite.com/semantic_storage_net.aspx# but its not helping me out because there is no proper documentation. So I'm asking this particularly for c#.net development.

Thanks

Comment: This has been asked many many times.  EAV's have their place, but they are few and far between.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224234/database-eav-pros-cons-and-alternatives -- with that, I'm going to vote to close, as there are numerous answers to the same question.

Comment: Thanks dear for providing me URL, I'm clear about it I need to use EAV but my question is about c#.net as I have entered a url.